# Image Resizing Service [Rails 5]

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, image-resizing

I'm building a project about **Uploading image and resizing them**, for the moment we are using `gem FastImage` which is perfect for getting image url. But i can't find any `Resizing Gem`.

What i want!

- Get size of that image
- Get width
- Get height
- Resize that image (would be perfect if i can scale that image, no croping).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look on [Carrierwave gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). It offers everything you want including the resizing part.

You can upload a image by  a remote url as:

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <label>My Avatar URL:</label>
    <%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) if @user.avatar? %>
    <%= f.text_field :remote_avatar_url %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

And maybe resize it as:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  version :resized do
    # returns an image with a maximum width of 100px 
    # while maintaining the aspect ratio
    # 10000 is used to tell CW that the height is free 
    # and so that it will hit the 100 px width first
    process :resize_to_fit => [100, 10000]
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need to do this manually not (hard code) to model :)